# How to represent this statement in RDF?

Tags: rdf, freebase, wikidata

```
My iPhone 6's screen size is 6 inches and red color.

Vocabulary are the following:

iPhone 6
screen
size
6 inches
color
red
```

Questions:
1) How to link 'iPhone 6' node with the 'screen' node?
2) 'screen' has two properties: 'size' & color

Possible relationships:
1) `[iPhone6, screen, ?]`  what's the object here?

2)

```
[screen, color, red]
[screen, size, 6 inches]
```

Is this appropriate to express as Compound Value Type in KB like Freebase? Reading the Freebase's documentation, it seems CVT is intended to express complex value types with a time dimension, such as an event or a population over time.

Comment: n-ary relations in RDF are modeled via blank nodes or you justadd an intermediate node instead. a typical solution would be `:iPhone6 :screen [:size "6"^^unit:inches ; :color :red ] .`

Comment: Is 'screen' a relationship or node name in your modeling? In Freebase, there is a Compound Value Type.

Comment: @user697911, both :-). In RDF, properties (but not their occurences) are first-class citizens. They might have their own properties etc. They are regular URIs.